# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast when listening to Firestore collection

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to listen to a Firestore collection and fill out a `ListView`. For some reason I'm getting an error that says `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast` and I don't see why.

The collection:
[image]

The variables and the listener:

```
  var tempFriendsList = {};
  var friendsList = {};

void initialize() {
    final uid = database.getUID();
    final friendsCollectionName = 'friends_' + uid;
    final friendsCollection = firestore.collection(friendsCollectionName).orderBy("username");
    friendsCollection.snapshots().listen((event) {

      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        tempFriendsList.add(doc.data());
      }
      setState(() {
        friendsList = tempFriendsList;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the widget that uses the `friendsList` variable:

```
Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: friendsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  if (friendsList.isNotEmpty) {
                    final user = User.fromJson(friendsList[index]);
                    final uid = user.uid;
                    final username = user.username;

                    return Text(username);
                  }

                  return Text('');
                },
              ),
          ),
```

This is my user model:

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  String username = ''; //Empty during Firebase Auth. Afterwards, this should be filled with the value from Firestore

  User({
    required this.uid,
    required this.username
  });

  User.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json): //Transform JSON into User
        uid = json?['uid'] as String, //STACK TRACE POINTS HERE AS #0
        username = json?['username'] as String;

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{ //Transforms User into JSON
    'uid': uid,
    'username': username,
  };

}
```

Comment: can reproduce with your firebase code as well

Comment: try to create the equality , copyWith and toString methods and try again. and change the `Map<dynamic, dynamic> `to `Map<String, dynamic>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Wasn't declaring my lists correctly.

I had to change from

```
  var tempFriendsList = {};
  var friendsList = {};
```

to

```
  var tempFriendsList = [{}];
  var friendsList = [{}];
```

I also had to clear the lists before the listener loops through all objects.

```
void initialize() {
    final uid = database.getUID();
    final friendsCollectionName = 'friends_' + uid;
    final friendsCollection = firestore.collection(friendsCollectionName).orderBy("username");
    friendsCollection.snapshots().listen((event) {
      tempFriendsList = [];
      friendsList = [];

      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        tempFriendsList.add(doc.data());
      }
      setState(() {
        friendsList = tempFriendsList;
      });
    });
  }
```